# Creating index for specific values only

Tags: oracle, index, performance, query-performance

We have a query that is called very frequently, so I would like to improve performance, but some colleagues are concerned about the index's size and its impact on inserts an updates.

```
SELECT field1, field2 
  FROM table1 
  WHERE field3 = '101'
  AND   field2 = @variable
```

Table `table1` has about 5 million rows, but only about 2000 has `field3 = 101`.

```
 CREATE TABLE table1 (
   field1 varchar
   field2 int
   field3 int);
```

Would it be possible to create and index for (field2, field1) only for these 2000 rows in oracle  11g?
How can I do it?

Comment: Which version of Oracle is this for?

Comment: Do you plan to upgrade the database to Oracle 12c? Oracle 12c provides a new function "Partial Indexing" where you can define indexes only on specific partitions of a table. Of course, in this case your table must be partitioned and one partition would contain `field3 = 101` values. See [Partial Indexes for Partitioned Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-256BA7EE-BF49-42DE-9B38-CD2480A73129.htm#VLDBG14102) and [artial Indexes for Partitioned Tables in Oracle Database 12c Release 1](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/partial-indexes-for-partitioned-tables-12cr1)

Comment: Update performance should not be affected unless you modify column `field3`.

Answer (score 6):

[Database SQL Language Reference - CREATE INDEX](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/CREATE-INDEX.html)

> "Oracle does not index table rows in which all key columns are null
>   except in the case of bitmap indexes."

Demo

```
create table t as select level as field3 from dual connect by level <= 1000000;
alter table t add field3_ind as (case when field3 = 101 then field3 end);
create index t_ix_field3_ind on t (field3_ind);
```

---

```
select * from t where field3_ind = 101;
```

[image: Execution Plan]

---

```
select    segment_name
         ,segment_type
         ,bytes

from      dba_segments 

where     owner        =  'DMARKOVITZ' 
      and segment_name in ('T','T_IX_FIELD3_IND')

order by  segment_name             
;
```

---

```
+-----------------+--------------+----------+
| SEGMENT_NAME    | SEGMENT_TYPE | BYTES    |
+-----------------+--------------+----------+
| T               | TABLE        | 13631488 |
+-----------------+--------------+----------+
| T_IX_FIELD3_IND | INDEX        | 65536    |
+-----------------+--------------+----------+
```

P.s.
The use of virtual column makes the querying more user friendly.

If the index would have been defined as -

```
create index t_ix_field3 on t (case when field3 = 101 then field3 end);
```

then in order to use the index, the query should have looked like -

```
select * from t where case when field3 = 101 then field3 end = 101;
```